# Which one is correct gramatically?

Tags: questions, tag-questions

It had to be me didn't it / hadn't it ?

Which one's correct and why ?

Comment: Did you try searching for ["tag questions"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=tag+questions) in ELL? Did you do any research in google? What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **It had to be me, hadn't it?**
>
> **It had to be me, didn't it**?

I think both are correct.But Americans might prefer *didn't it?*

The British might prefer__ hadn't it?_

Though *had* and *have* are main verbs The British  might use **have**  and **had** in the question tags.

Since *have* and *had* are considered main verbs, Americans  might prefer the helping verbs do and did in the question tags.

Comment: Brits today *usually* use DO rather than HAVE in tag questions anyway, but it's especially the case with OP's particular example.That's partly because negated ***hadn't it*** is a bit more of a "tongue-twister" that can't easily be further contracted (unlike ***did not it = didn't it = dinnit***). But also partly because in this *specific* context, ***had*** is to some extent a ***different word*** - which is often pronounced **HAT** (or **HASS** for the present tense form) to distinguish it from the standard auxiliary verb. And that "different verb" doesn't work well as a "tag" form.

Comment: What you answered definitely ***isn't*** wrong (that's my upvote! :) All I'm saying is that your *British **might** prefer__ hadn't it?_* might rather overstate the case. Only a tiny fraction of Brits would have that preference, though it's almost certainly an even smaller fraction of *Americans*.